# Same Hash value on different input

Tags: php, forms, post, hash, sha

I have got this html form:

```html
<form action="seite2.php" method="post">
    Benutzername:<br />
    <input type="Text" name="username"><br /><br />

    Passwort:<br />
    <input type="Password" name="passwort" />

    <input type="Submit" value="Absenden" />
</form>
```

on seite2.php I have got this code first, to check the Hash value:

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$passwort = $_POST["passwort"];

$pass = sha1($passwort);

echo $pass;
```

then, I want to check wether username&&password is correct and compare the hashs. Lets say username is: mue. and password is: pass. I get this hash: da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709.

```
if($username == "mue" AND $pass=="da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709")
{
    echo '<p>';
    echo "Herzlich Willkommen";
    echo '</p>';
}
else
{
    echo '<p>';
    echo "Login failed";
    echo '</p>';
```

But in my Browser, I get following response:
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
Login failed.

And no matter which user or password I'll take, the hash given back from the browser is always the same.

Comment: That's the hash of an empty string. What does `var_dump($passwort);` show?

Comment: What about `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: null, don't know why

Comment: var_dump($_POST) shows empty array

Comment: both your form and php file exist on the same working location? or they resist on different folders?

Comment: I've had this problem yesterday, that POST did not work. But GET worked fine. But I can't explain why GET work but POST doesn't

Comment: they are at the same location

Comment: What does `var_dump($_GET);` show?

Comment: 'username' => string 'mue' (length=3)
  'passwort' => string 'test' (length=4)

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: _This is a long shot_ But if GET works and POST does not, check this parameter in your `php.ini` has a **P** in it `variables_order = "GPCS"`

Comment: variables_order="GPCS"

Comment: Just curious, why `passwort` instead of `password`? Seems like an easy way to confuse a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

The code is ok,i try it and work but the sha1 of "pass" is:

```
   9d4e1e23bd5b727046a9e3b4b7db57bd8d6ee684
```

maybe you modify the worse file. see your editor and see if you change the right "seite2.php". if you change the path location of this file maybe the old file remained in the IDE and you edit this one and no the new one.